# Unread number i pantheon email doesn't update

Tags: pantheon-mail

Unread number doesn't update, even after restarting the email client.

[image]

Any way to force update this or trigger this automatically?

Comment: Still not fixed Elementary 6.0

Answer (score 0):

**There are alot of issues using gmail in patheon mail**, I'd suggest you install another mail client instead my personal prefference is thunderbird

You can get it through the terminal using.

```
$ apt-get install thunderbird
```